# What happens when you background a function which calls another function?

Tags: bash, shell, background-process

I'm trying to find out how to background a process in a script that calls another function and reliably terminate it when ready. Will I have to move it all into one function?

```
function dosomething {
    while :
    do
    printsomething "doing something"
    done
}

function printsomething {
    echo $@
}

function otherfunction {
    dosomething &
    TMP_PID=$!
}

function killsomething {
    quit_test=`ps -p "$TMP_PID" | sed '1d' | awk '{print $1}'`
    if [ "$quit_test" != "" ] ; then
        (kill $TMP_PID >/dev/null)
    fi
}

## MAIN

    TMP_PID=""
    echo "starting program"
    otherfunction
    sleep 5s
    killsomething
```

Comment: Not very clear on what youre trying to accomplish, however you can call functions from a backgrounded function without issues. Unless you do another background call from within the first background call, theres no reason it wont work. Have you tried it?

Comment: yeah, its doing some strange things and ultimately wont stop.

Comment: your example works fine, please post something that actually fails so I can debug.

Comment: oh and you don't need to initialize variables.

Comment: It's never a bad idea to initialize variable.  This is particularly relevant to variables whose first use is inside a function; depending on the shell and function definition (`function f{}` vs `f(){}`), the variable's scope may be limited to the function otherwise.

Comment: Moreover, you *must* initialize variables if you use `set -u` to detect uses of uninitialized variables.